# Java and Fingerprint Recognition

Tags: java, image-processing, fingerprint

Has anyone implement fingerprint recognition system in Java?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027847/fingerprint-matching-recognition-algorithms-implementations?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

For example this comes with java api for linux and windows platforms: http://www.griaulebiometrics.com/page/en-us/manual/fingerprint-sdk-java

If you are interested about fingerprint recognition as such, then this book is helpful: http://bias.csr.unibo.it/maltoni/handbook/ For a fast overview, check http://www.cse.unr.edu/~bebis/CS790Q/Lect/BK2_Chapters_1_2.ppt

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to this open source lib which is well maintained:

[sourceafis-java](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sourceafis/)

with the official code repo: https://bitbucket.org/robertvazan/sourceafis-java/src/1ec1cb4f210d?at=default