# Fingerprint matching/recognition algorithms/implementations

Tags: python, algorithm, matching, fingerprint

Throughout this day I've been investing time into fingerprint matching/recognition algorithms/implementations in the world of programming. Though it's a bit of a vague because I can't seem to find anything really related.

I'm basically looking for two next things:

- Fingerprint recognition: verify that the image is actually a fingerprint and so can be matched with another fingerprint
- Fingerprint matching: match two fingerprint from items to see if the actually are equal

All operations will be done on images, so I don't have anything to do with hardware. I've found a few things such as the Java Fingerprint SDK, etc and also found almost duplicate questions on Stackoverflow but they are either outdated or are not really clear.

Could anyone point me a direction to algorithms/implementations (open source) who can do these two things? I want to implement it myself in Python in the end.

Comment: Hi i am also facing the same problem now. Have you got any solution for this in python?? Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find any solution? I have the same request, having the image of the fingerprint in PNG and a database of images in PNG to compare, need the Python library to make the comparison and identify the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this open-source library http://sourceforge.net/projects/sourceafis/ by Robert Vazan.
it's a .net implementation and java port is in progress.

Sample code also present if you checkout their mercurial repo from the [development](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sourceafis/develop) branch.

```
http://sourceafis.hg.sourceforge.net:8000/hgroot/sourceafis/sourceafis (read-only)
```

Kind regards,

Comment: Seems nice, only problem with Java: https://sourceforge.net/projects/sourceafis/forums/forum/1051112/topic/5169966 - maybe you could help me?

Comment: i guess you shouldn't be having problem with that. you can go through C# code and implement that in python if you like.. C# is pretty much open-source and very similar to java. (PS: if you like complete java port then i guess u'll hv to wait!!)

Comment: it's java not python !!