# Fingerprint Recognition System

Tags: python, c, opencv, image-processing, fingerprint

I am going to design a Fingerprint Recognition System that involves recognizing fingerprint from image, feature extraction and matching. I am willing to implement it through C and Python, that library will be written in C and docked to Python as a module. Here are my questions:

1. Is there any books that you can recommend me in this field (except Handbook of Fingerprint Recognition)?
2. I need a device that will simply scan the fingerprint and save it as an image which I can use later through my code. But I can't seem to find one. All of them have their own software for matching and don't allow me to bypass it. Are there any known devices for such task or shall I write my own driver for one of them?
3. Would you recommend OpenCV?

Comment: Basic fingerprint scanning can be done with just a camera, so you could start with just your webcam as source of images.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027847/fingerprint-matching-recognition-algorithms-implementations?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is clearly computer vision task, so the answer is: yes, OpenCV is good for the task.

The question of fingerprint recognition already was discussed in in OpenCV forum. So you can start from [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/6364/fingerprint-matching-in-mobile-devices-android/#6370) .