# Fingerprint reader for Java

Tags: java, fingerprint

I want to use fingerprint reader in my `Java` application, i want to buy any fingerprint reader appliance, but i don't know these,

- Where the data is kept ?
- Can I use it in Java application ?
- Do you know any documentation for this ?

Comment: Google is your friend here. http://bit.ly/U46oDG

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a fingerprint reader api/sdk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277373/is-there-a-fingerprint-reader-api-sdk)

Comment: This might help:
[Java and Fingerprint Recognition][1]



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090818/java-and-fingerprint-recognition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be useful for you:
http://en.pudn.com/search_db.asp?keyword=java+fingerprint

Answer (score 0):

> You will get better idea from fingerprint reader appliance manual.
>   You can know how to connect and read data from device